# T4 template to write basic class definitions

Tags: t4

I am still trying to learn...alot. It is my understanding that neither an Interface nor Abstract class can "require" a class to have constructors. So, being pretty bad at T4's, can somebody point me in the right direction of creating a T4 template that creates the following code:

```
Make a T4 template that
        1. reads all the classes in a file or namespace
        2. produces code that has:
            2.1  interface name of "I"+ClassName, e.g. "IClassName"
            2.2  model name of ClassName+"Model", e.g.  "ClassNameModel"
            2.3  model code of:
                    public ClassNameModel<T> 
                        where T: IClassName, new()
                        {
                            private readonly T t;

                            public ClassNameModel()
                            {
                                t = new T();
                            }
                            public ClassNameModel(T t)
                            {
                                this.t = t;
                            }
                        }
```

Thanks for any help. TIA

Comment: I made a tutorial last year to generate simple classes from text definitions. Maybe it can help you https://tim-maes.com/2019/03/28/t4-beginner-tutorial/ , you just need to work out how to get the classNames from a certain namespace ;-)

Comment: @TimMaes Very helpful! Now to read the classes out of visual studio?? Thanks.